# May I omit a default argument when calling a pointer to a static function?

Tags: c++, static-members, pointer-to-member

I'm afraid I'm going to expose my ignorance, but hey, I don't understand this.

If I define a static member function inline like this:

```
struct S {
    static int f(int i = 0) {
        return -i;
    }
};
```

and then I take a pointer to S::f:

```
auto fPtr {&S::f};
int (*fp)(int) {S::f}
```

either way, it doesn't matter, then I'm not allowed to call it without arguments:

```
auto a = fPtr(); // error: too few arguments to function
auto b = fp();   // error: too few arguments to function
```

While instead I can do this:

```
S s;
auto c = s.f();
```

which is strange since I thought that, on many levels, static member functions are really not associated to any object, yet they do not work as normal functions if they have default arguments.

I couldn't find any explanation of this behaviour in the Standard, but I'm not really sure that I'm not missing it.

Comment: No. Default arguments are not a part of the function type and not a part of a function pointer. They are a part of a function itself. They are only considered when a function is called directly using its name. `s.f()` or `S::f()` make use of the name of the function so the default arguments can be considered. `fPtr()` and `fp()` do not. There is no way to link `fPtr` back to `S::f`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've found where the Standard explains that default arguments are not part of the function type: [link](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#8)
It still sounds odd, as the compiler appears to know that there's a missing argument, at least when it must generate the function call, so in a sense it _knows_ the type of the function.

Comment: The type of the function is `int(int)`. The type of the function pointer is `int(*)(int)`. Of course the compiler knows the type and it knows that an argument is missing. That's why it reports an error. Do you expect it to fill the missing argument in instead? Based on what?

Comment: A function without argument is not called the same way as one with one argument. Default argument are mainly equivalent of typing the extra argument at each call site from  the point of view of generated code. While a compiler could theorically create proxy, that was not done. Workaround is that you would define a function with 0 argument that call the other one and remove default argument.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, I wasn't clear. Of course it knows. I was trying to understand  why it knows the complete type of the function but it cannot know that there are default arguments. From my point of view, I can't see any difference between saying:
a) here's a pointer to a function, please call it without arguments, and
b) please call S::f() 
Only in the second case the compiler sees the _whole_ definition and, given the missing argument, effectively generates a call to S::f(0)

Comment: Default arguments are not a part of the function type or the function pointer. The compiler has no way to determine whether the actual function has default arguments, and if so, which ones. This information is simply not there. Whereas when calling `S::f()`, the information is there, it is in the declaration of `S::f`.

Comment: @Phil1970 The reason why I didn't try that and discovered this fact, is that I was trying to use std::experimental::source_location::current() as implemented gcc. I wanted an abbreviation because it's too long. If I call it within another (short-named) function, I get the wrong location. So I thought I might define a `src_loc` which points to it. It turns out that this static function is implemented with default arguments in [GNU standard library](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/source_location;hb=57d76ee9cf6265e012fad6286adfaeaba9414c11)

Comment: Do you have control on both sides? If so, an alternative that would probably works is using  a class instead. Constructor would capture the file and line and then you could call a member function...

Comment: When you do `S::f()` or `s.f()`, the compiler generate something similar to **1)** push `0` *(default value)* on the stack, **2)** call function `f`. When you take the address of a function, so that it can be called later, only the information for **(2)** is stored in the function pointer. And C++ is a langage aimed at efficiency so a pointer to a function only store that pointer and not any extra information.To make it more clear, suppose, you have a function `g(int i = 2, int j = 3)` the compiler would have to save 2 integers. An alternative woud be `std::function` and lambda expression,

Comment: @Phil1970 The best solution I've found is the `src_clone` function in [cppreference's example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/current), which ironically uses a default argument as well...